# asynchronous webservice call. No (Begin...) method available!

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webservice-client

I know this has been addressed before but I have service that returns a string like so.

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string Hello()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return "Hello User";
    }
}
```

I've read many examples that say I need to call the method like this:

```
        MyService my = new MyService();
        AsyncCallback async = new AsyncCallback(callback);
        my.BeginHello();
        Console.WriteLine("Called webservice");
```

The thing is when I added reference I coudn't get the BeginHello method. All I saw was the HelloAsync. So I used it like this in my console app.

```
        MyService my = new MyService();
        AsyncCallback async = new AsyncCallback(callback);
        my.HelloAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Called webservice");
```

and defined a private callback method like this

```
    private void callback(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        Console.Write("Webservice finished executing.");
    }
```

In doing so, I get an error like this:

> An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'AsyncWebserviceCall.Program.callback(System.IAsyncResult)

Why dont I get the BeginHello method & Why do I get this error as above?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please show us the whole class (both the callback and the method that calls the webservice)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the code is being run inside your `public static void Main(string[] args)` function then you need to make `private void callback(IAsyncResult res)` a static method:

```
private static void callback(IAsyncResult res)
{
    Console.Write("Webservice finished executing.");
}
```

That's why you're getting that error.

From ASP.NET 2.0 onwards there were some changes to how you make async web service calls. Do this instead:

```
MyService my = new MyService();
my.HelloCompleted += CallBack;
my.HelloAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Called service.");
Console.ReadLine();  // Wait, otherwise console app will just exit.
```

Your callback method signature changes to:

```
private static void CallBack(object sender, HelloCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Webservice finished executing.");
}
```

**More info:**

From Visual Studio 2005 onwards the Add Web Reference proxy generator no longer creates the `BeginXXX/EndXXX` methods. These methods were deprecated in favour of the `XXXAsync/XXXCompleted` pattern.

If you really need to work with the `BeginXXX/EndXXX` style async methods you can use one of the following methods:

1. Use the [`WSDL.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=VS.80).aspx) tool to create the proxy. For example:

   `wsdl.exe /out:MyService.cs http://somedomain.com/MyService.asmx?wdsl`

   Include the generated `MyService.cs` file in your project and use that instead of a Web Reference. You need to open a Visual Studio command prompt for this so that the .NET Framework SDK binaries are in your path.
2. There is apparently a hack in Visual Studio (it may no longer be available). For more info see this MS Connect case:

> [Begin/End Async WebService Proxy Methods Not Generated in Web Application Projects](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/288660/begin-end-async-webservice-proxy-methods-not-generated-in-web-application-projects)

My advice would be to embrace the new approach.

Comment: Thanks. That solved one problem. what about the missing BeginHello method?

Comment: Thanks Kev. so you're saying that ASP.NET 2.0 onwards they removed the {Begin...} prefix to async calls?

Comment: I dont think this line will work: my.HelloCompleted += CallBack; I will add an aswer shwoing what I did that got it working. Meanwhile how does this guy have both methods available? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70441/Calling-Web-Service-Functions-Asynchronously-from-.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I changed on the client side to get it working.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyService my = new MyService();
        my.HelloCompleted +=new HelloCompletedEventHandler(my_HelloCompleted);
        my.HelloAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Called webservice");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void my_HelloCompleted(object sender, HelloCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Webservice finished executing in my_HelloCompleted.");
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. :) From C#2.0 onwards you don't need to specify the `new HelloCompletedEventHandler`. Just do: `my.HelloCompleted += my_HelloCompleted`.

Comment: Thanks Kev. Will try that out. :)